# C++ program starts execution from main and ends at main?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{

public:
A()
   {
    cout<<"A is called";

    }
}a;

int main()

{
    cout<<"main is called";

}
```

but here the A funtion is called first and main is called later
what is the mechanism behind it ?

Comment: read about static storage duration, `a` is global variable, so it is created before entering `main` function.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` should not be used ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) and `using namespace std;`should be avoided ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Together they reinforce some of the other's worst behaviours, resulting in some very hard to understand errors. Do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is that the global variable `a` of type `A` is created first. In the construtor you output the text `A is called` and than the program starts with the main funtion.

So what you see is to be expected and you take from it that prior to the execution of `main()` global variables have to be created.

You can find more information if you look for `static storage duration`, which global objects have.

**NOTE:** The order of creation of objects with static storage duration is *unspecified* by the standard, so any order can be observed.